How much HPC time goes on different basic operations like matrix multiplication, linear programming, sorting etc.?
I'm teaching a course on parallel computing, and have been trying to find a breakdown of how much high performance computing time is spent on different basic building-block operations, but haven't found anything.
The sorts of building-blocks I'm thinking of are

BLAS (like matrix multiplication, solving linear systems)
solving differential equations
sorting
graph algorithms (like shortest path, multi-commodity flow, maximum matchings, clique-finding)
linear programming
other optimisation (like branch-and-bound, travelling salesman)

For example, I know that deep learning is mostly matrix multiplication, but how can I find what fraction of HPC time around the world is spent on deep learning?  I know that climate modelling is mostly solving PDEs, but how can I find (a) what fraction of HPC is solving climate models, and (b) what fraction of solving PDEs is also one of the other building blocks like matrix multiplication or solving linear systems?
Web queries like 'fraction of HPC time "matrix multiplication"' return lots of matrix multiplication algorithms, but nothing like what I'm looking for.  Can anyone suggest how to find this data?
I don't mind if it is for the top500 type HPC or regular university HPC clusters -- just something to get a feel for what the "real-ish" problems are.

I doubt you will be able to find solid info on this given that most of the large HPC systems are private or government-affiliated. Here is a NASA report from 10 years ago describing their (then) current HPC capacity and how well-suited it is for massive scale CFD, which consists of massive iterative linear solvers and differential equations.

https://www.archer2.ac.uk/news/2022/02/07/software-usage-data.html MIght be of interest

Thanks @IanBush.  That is of great interest!

Thanks @whpowell96.  I'm not after really solid data -- just a general sense.  Thanks for letting me know the building blocks of CFD.
